# Java SE 7: alternative to try-catch for testing

Tags: java, junit, try-catch

I have a bunch of similar methods called from `@Before beforeTest()` in a test class:

```
//...

private void addClientDetails() {
    try {
        clientDetailsService.addClientDetails(testClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private void addUserRoles() {
    try {
        adminController.addUserRoles(addedRoles);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

private void deleteAddedRoles() {
    for (String role : addedRoles) {
        try {
            adminController.deleteUserRole(role);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

private void deleteClients() {
    try {
        clientsController.deleteClient(testClient.getClientId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

//...
```

It is really unnecessary to catch possible exceptions and inconvenient to add some ifs here. These are the auxiliary methods to prepare tests or clean up after tests.

**How to get rid of those ridiculous `try {...} catch (...) {}` constructs?**

The idea was to create a new method with `Runnable` argument but this leads to even more cumbersome syntax:

```
private void deleteClients() {
    trySilently(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
}

private void trySilently(Runnable task) {
    try {
        task.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

In JDK 1.8 method reference can help. But is there any beautiful solution in terms of JDK 1.7?

It is understood ignoring exceptions is a bad practice. Nevertheless the question is exactly how to do it in a graceful way.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the exceptions? Surely that's what you're testing for. If you want to know when exceptions occur, just add `throws Exception` to the test method's signature.

Comment: Let your methods throw the exceptions, ignoring exceptions is a terrible practice and should never be done

Comment: Probably you'd better to use one of many mocking frameworks rather than write stubs like that.

Comment: I can't imagine how you can trust your test results if you silently ignore exceptions thrown by your test methods.

Comment: As I pointed in the question those are not the test cases and I'm always sure that the test results can be trusted because if something really bad happens in one of those methods and will get ignored I'll get assertion errors in subsequent calls. But usually I get errors like "something already exists" or "does not exist". This I don't care because I only need to make sure I tried to add/delete something.

Comment: So, Oleg, where's the difference if the setup method fails or the test? It usually is prefered to **[fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)** rather than fail some time later without any hint what the original problem was.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov: Okay. So is the approach in my answer useful, then? It lets you ignore those exceptions without having individual exception blocks like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare that those methods throw exceptions, e.g.:

```
private void addClientDetails() throws Exception {
    clientDetailsService.addClientDetails(testClient);
}
```

...then use reflection to call them:

```
String[] methods = {"addClientDetails", "addUserDetails" /*, ...*/};
for (String method : methods) {
    try {
        TestClass.class.getMethod(method).invoke(testObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // STRONGLY RECOMMEND DOING SOMETHING HERE SO YOU'RE NOT SILENTLY
        // IGNORING EXCEPTIONS
    }
}
```

(You'll need to keep the handler in `deleteAddedRoles`, though, since it loops, if you *really* want to ignore exceptions from `adminController.deleteUserRole`.)

---

**Note**: It seems very strange to be *completely ignoring* those exceptions. It's hard to imagine how you can trust your test results if you silently ignore exceptions from the test code. But I'm assuming you know what you're doing... :-)

Comment: " then use reflection to call them:" yuk yuk yuk yuk yuk. This just seems like bad advice - OP should understand why these exceptions are being thrown, and thus handle them properly.

Comment: @AndyTurner: As I said above, ignoring the exceptions seems like a bad idea. But the OP didn't ask for advice on exception handling, just how to avoid all of these try-ignores (as I like to call them). :-) I believe reflection is how you loop through a list of methods in a loop like this in Java 7, so...

Comment: If these methods are the test cases, it would be better to point OP towards JUnit or some other standard testing framework, rather than rolling-your-own like this. And if they're not the test cases, you don't need to call them in a loop. (Yes, JUnit is using reflection under the covers; but it's doing sensible default things that don't need to be reinvented)

Comment: @AndyTurner: I'm just answering the question that the OP actually asked. There are already plenty of comments pointing out that what he's asked to do is a bad idea, including at least one pointing to testing frameworks.

Comment: You are in the first bit, but all the stuff about reflection is making assumptions about how OP invokes those private methods. Presumably they're being invoked already, somehow; there's no reason to change that (other than perhaps propagating the `throws` from those methods too).

Comment: @AndyTurner: Yes, there is a reason: To avoid having to wrap each individual one in a `try/catch`, which would just move the problem from within the methods to where you call them, rather than doing what the OP said he wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

In TestNG there is no problem for method annotated with @BeforeClass/@BeforeMethod to **throw** exception.

Why wouldn't you just

```
@BeforeClass
private void addClientDetails() throws Exception{
     clientDetailsService.addClientDetails(testClient);
}
```

This also works for @Test methods.

Silenty catching exception is very bad idea. How could you trust your tests then? are you sure that exceptions tha occured is no problem indeed? If yes, then exception should not be thrown in first place.

Also, you could redesing your API to use unchecked exceptions. Just wrap any checked exceptions in RuntimeException, and throw RuntimeException.